# Almost sure convergence of sample mean

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have a sequence of events $(A_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$ with $\mathbb{P} (A_n) = 1/n^2$ for all $n$. We have $X_n = n^2 1_{A_n} - 1$, and $m_n = (X_1 + ... + X_n )/n$ is the sample mean. I would like to show that $m_n \to -1$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: That is a lovely counter-intuitive result, since clearly $E[X_n]=0$ and so $E[m_n]=0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know $\sum P(A_n) <\infty$ so by Borel-Cantelli $A_n^c$ occurs eventually a.s. It follows that for almost every $\omega$, there is an $n(\omega)$ such that $X_n = -1$ for all $n>n(\omega)$. The result follows immediately.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. That makes a lot of sense now.